# What is the significance of @javax.persistence.Lob annotation in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, java-ee-7

When should I use `@javax.persistence.Lob` annotation in JPA? What datatypes can be annotated by this annotation?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`@javax.persistence.Lob` signifies that the annotated field should be represented as BLOB (binary data) in the database.

You can annotate any `Serializable` data type with this annotation.
In JPA, upon persisting (retrieval) the field content will be serialized (deserialized) using standard Java serialization.

Common use of `@Lob` is to annotate a `HashMap` field inside your Entity to store some of the object properties which are not mapped into database columns. That way, all the unmapped values can be stored in the database in one column in their binary representation.

Of course, the price that is paid is that, as they are stored in binary format, they are not searchable using the JPQL/SQL.

Comment: Can we use @Lob for inserting some data( Some string with many images)?

Comment: For an existing table created using SQL queries, does `@Lob` makes sense? I don't get what happens behind the scenes when people say "Support for large objects". @Zeilu

Answer (score 27):

According to: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Lob.html

**@Lob** Specifies that a persistent property or field should be persisted as a large object to a database-supported large object type.

> @javax.persistence.Lob signifies that the annotated field should be
>   represented as BLOB (binary data) in the DataBase.

I suppose in database it could be not only binary data but character-based.
As we could have BLOB and CLOB. Here's examples in java code:

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "CHARS", columnDefinition = "CLOB")
private String chars;`

@Lob
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name = "DATA", columnDefinition = "BLOB", nullable = false)
private byte[] data;
```

Comment: Fetch type Lazy does not work in this case, cause you are using byte[] to store your data.

Comment: That is right! `@Lob` is used to map `Binary` **OR** `large character objects`!

Comment: For an existing table created using SQL queries, does `@Lob` makes sense? I don't get what happens behind the scenes when people say "Support for large objects". @levrun

Answer (score 3):

In my JPA + mysql test, java entity class field annotated with @Lob will generated `longtext` mysql column by auto ddl.