# hibernate reading byte array wrong

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am trying to read byte array from mysql which is stored as **BLOB** into the db. I created a rest api which is based on Spring Boot and Hibernate. Everything works fine but byte[] array seems a little bit different than stored into db.

This is the byte array in database : `11,7,5`
This is what hibernate gets from db :`[49, 49, 44, 55, 44, 53]`
This is what I see in my browser : `data: "MTEsNyw1"`

Here is my hibernate code

```
class MyData{
    ...
    @Column(name="data",columnDefinition="BLOB")//this is what I tried but did not work!
    private byte[] data;
}
```

And with that, I want to return data array which is 11,7,5 from Jackson Mapper. Could you help me with annotations or something useful with this?

Comment: Can you try to add the annotation: `@Lob(type = LobType.BLOB)`

Comment: type does not resolved, I only can add @Lob interface, can not add any property

Comment: Try to just run with @Lob and see if it helps.

Comment: It does not help

Comment: Another thing you can try... @Basic annotation as used in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38632722/3179169

Comment: I did try and result is still the same. data in store is "5", and written as [53] to console. data is 11,7,5 in database, and written as [49, 49, 44, 55, 44, 53] to console

Comment: Those are ascii values for the numbers. Can you check the contents of the byte[] and then see how you read from it?

Comment: In your Controller, try `response.setHeader` and/or `response.setContentType` in your GET method's response.