# Store a complicated structure with data for future use

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a complicated structure (ArrayList of specific Class which inherits other Class) that I use as part of my calculations.

The thing is that sometimes I want to reuse the data inside this structure again in another time (i.e. after 1 week).

I tried to extend current tables or even create a new table but it didn't work out.

I want to find a way to store this data for future using.

I don't mind to store it in the database but only as-is, and not split it to all the variables types.

The code itself it's quite huge but here is a small example of the idea behind the complexity of the structure (The structure is more complicated):

```
public class A<T extends B> {
    private DataTable<T> table = null;
    private List<?>[] minimalCommonSets = null;
    private Handler[] allHandlers;
}


public class DataTable<T extends TableElement> {

    private TableElement[] table;
    private int[] size;
}


public abstract class TableElement {

}

public abstract class Handler<T, S>  {

}

public class C extends B {

    private int N;

    private Set<String> S1;


    private Set<String> S2;

    private List<D> d;

    protected E e;
}


private A<C> STORE_IT;
```

I want to store an instance of A (STORE_IT).

Comment: Is it serializable? you could also use something like gson to create a Json representation if the classes contained are simple enough.

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you provide source code.

Comment: @Bsquare - I wanted but it's quite complicated... I tried to build a demo (mini-structure) of my code. hope it will be clear enough.

Comment: @Assafs - right now it's not. I thought about the GSON but it's a huge amount of data, and the JSON will be very very big... is it something that acceptable?

Comment: Do you want to persist the data model, or the data themself?

Comment: @Bsquare Only data.

Comment: OK, what do you mean by 'huge amount of data'? If it is so huge, you should consider using a Buffered system, to dump data in a file, or a database, iteratively, instead of all at once (which may lead to too high Memory consumption).

Comment: I never extract this data so I don't really know what its size, but I assume it's quite big. maybe the JSON conversion will surprise me. anyway - now I'm getting IllegalArgumentException as probably one of the subclasses is making some trouble...

Comment: Do you need to "see" the data in the Database? If not just serialize it as a byte array and store it as BLOB (binara large object). Take a look here for serialization: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836646/java-serializable-object-to-byte-array For BLOB look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511133/what-is-the-significance-of-javax-persistence-lob-annotation-in-jpa

Comment: @AndreasHauschild - No, I don't need to see. sounds good actually. just a question - if I have a lot of subclasses, including abstracts and interfaces - do I need to serialize each one of them..? 'cause due to the complexity of the structure, I don't think I can...

Comment: @Dvir If you serialize your root object everything which belongs to it will be serialized too.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions could be Serialization and Database.

Gson Serialization Library would be my goto for this kind of scenarios. (It is typesafe and handles both serialization and deserialization)
https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: I thought about the GSON but it's a huge amount of data, and the JSON will be very very big... is it something that acceptable?

Comment: are we talking of MB's (1-10MB's) of huge or like 1-10 nested Objects with avg of 10 - 50 params?? I think gson can handle such situattion with breeze, given the fact that it can deserialize for you without any extra work ....

Comment: interesting actually - does GSON has an advantage over BYTE? (I don't need it to be readable in the DB)

Comment: Than you could go for SQLite or any DB with java ORM toolchain available...

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be convert the data in Json and store it in a new table in db .  When ever data is required Json parsers can be used to again create the complex data structure after retrieving the json from db.